# How store URL with '&' character in SOAP message

Tags: c#, soap

I have created a Windows service which uploads media files (.ts, .mpg, ...) into a CDN FTP repository then the CDN invokes a web service to get a download link for each file.

The download link is like this:

`http://CompanyName-­‐yy.XXX.net/XXX/folder.asp?param1=636&param2=123`

Then I store all download links into a SOAP message and I invoke another web service.

My question: how do I save a url with the character `&` without encoding it? If I have to encode it, should the other party which receives my request decode it again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're sending an XML request so you *have* to encode it according to XML standards. This includes replacing `&` in values with the `&amp;` entity, unless you're using `CDATA` content.

Decoding it is the responsibility of the client, and unless he is using a completely barebones or selfwritten XML parser that should already be handled by the parser they use.

That said, I'm wondering how you are invoking the SOAP request to begin with? Usually when you create a web service adapter using the WSDL file you just fill out the corresponding class properties and send the request, without having to think about encoding at all.

Comment: first of all thanks for the reply , actually i don't use proxy class which allow to communicate by using object (imple or complexe object) since the generated proxy class contains a large amount of classes and child classe, it seems that fomrat the soap message manually is the accommodate solution

Answer (score 0):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226544(v=sql.80).aspx :

> In queries executed at the URL,
>   special characters are specified as
>   %xx, where xx is the hexadecimal value
>   of the character. The following table
>   lists these special characters and
>   describes their meanings. For more
>   information, see the RFC1738
>   specification at
>   http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1738.html.

Special character `&` is represented by `%26` in a URL.

---

Whoops, I see you want to encode an `&` within an XML, so use `&amp;` like SirViver said.

Comment: thanks for the reply , but in this case i should advise the other party about this change, but the library is already installed into the Set-up-box which will be sent to the market soon, BTW i'll try both solution (yours and SirViver) an i'll give you my feedback